# Dynamically added PostBackTrigger in Custom Server Control not beeing rendered correctly

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel, custom-controls, viewstate

I'm building a custom server control derived from `CompositeControl`.
The control contains a number of child controls (Labels, DropDownList, ListSearchExtender, etc). All of them reside inside an `UpdatePanel`.
The control also publishes events. For this I added two Properties: EnableCallBacks and CallBacksAsPostBacks. Those two properties should configure the postback behaviour of the update panel.

Any ideas what a correct implementation should look like?

I'm getting some problems with the way I implemented it:

- the PostBackTrigger does not always get rendered into the output html.
- Having both `Triggers.Add(trigger)` and `Controls.Add(_updatePanel)` inside the `CreateChildControls` methods leads to the PostBackTrigger always being rendered, even if I remove it later on (e.g. within RenderControl() or PreRender()). If I do not add the trigger here but later on, then it does never get rendered. At this stage I do not have the correct values of all my properties yet (e.g. `EnableCallBacks` and `CallBacksAsPostBacks`).
- It is not possible to place the statement of `Controls.Add(_updatePanel)` inside the RenderControl-method due to it beeing too late for AJAX (latest ist `PreRender()` otherwise I get an exception).
- Ideally I would instantiate all controls in CreateChildControls() and then set their values later on in e.g. PreRender or RenderControl
- Having both statements in the `PreRender` method results in, that the trigger gets rendered corretly depending on my settings in the containing page, but I don't get the DropDownList populated with its data from the ViewState (on call/postbacks).

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
     base.CreateChildControls();
    _updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
    _updatePanel.ID = "FprDropDownList_UpPnl";
    _updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

    _label = new FprLabel();
    _label.ID = "FprDropDownList_Lbl";
    _updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_label);

    _dropDownList = new DropDownList();
    _dropDownList.ID = "FprDropDownList_Ddl";
    _dropDownList.CssClass = "fprDropDownList";
    _dropDownList.AutoPostBack = true;
    _updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_dropDownList);

    _label.AssociatedControlID = _dropDownList.ClientID;

    _listSearchExtender = new ListSearchExtender();
    _listSearchExtender.ID = "FprDropDownList_Lse";
    _listSearchExtender.TargetControlID = _dropDownList.ClientID;
    _listSearchExtender.PromptPosition = ListSearchPromtPosition;
    _listSearchExtender.PromptCssClass = "fprListSearchExtender";
    _updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_listSearchExtender);

    _ddlPostBackTrigger = new PostBackTrigger();
    _ddlPostBackTrigger.ControlID = _dropDownList.ClientID;

    //_updatePanel.Triggers.Add(_ddlPostBackTrigger);
    Controls.Add(_updatePanel);
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs pE)
{
   if (EnableCallBacks) 
   { 
      _dropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged += DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged; 
   }
   if (EnableCallBacks && CallBacksAsPostBacks) 
   { 
     _updatePanel.Triggers.Add(_ddlPostBackTrigger); 
   }
   //Controls.Add(_updatePanel);
   base.OnPreRender(pE);
}

public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter pWriter)
{
   // Do some things... like set Enable-state of child controls
   base.RenderControl(pWriter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your dynamic controls in [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for the events to fire properly.

> Use this event for the following:
>
> - Check the IsPostBack property to
>     determine whether this is the first
>     time the page is being processed. The 
>     IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack
>     properties have also been set at this 
>     time.
> - Create or re-create dynamic
>     controls.
> - Set a master page
>     dynamically.
> - Set the Theme
>     property dynamically.
> - Read or set
>     profile property values.